# C# static inline method parameter

Tags: c#

For performance reasons, I'm trying to reduce the overhead of having a new instance of a reference type created every time a particular method is called.

As a basic example:

```
public int AccumulativeCount(Expression<Func<int>> exp)
{
    // usually do something useful with "exp". Instead put a
    // breakpoint and get the memory reference of exp via "&exp"
    return 1;
}
```

When it is called elsewhere in the code, the reference of exp in the AccumulativeCount method is different:

```
AccumulativeCount(() => 7);
```

Is there a way to make the parameter from the calling code static inline? In the example above the parameter "() => 7" is obviously never going to change, so there is no compelling reason why it should be recreated every time.

I'm aware that I could change the calling code to be:

```
public static Expression<Func<int>> MyStaticCountExp = () => 7;
// ... later in the code
AccumulativeCount(MyStaticCountExp);
```

The reason why I'm against the above is the expression only makes sense in the context that it is a parameter for. Also the code is not as clean as it could be. Is there something like:

```
AccumulativeCount(static () => 7); // does not compile
```

Comment: I highly doubt you'd notice any perceivable performance impact from this. If you're going to make such minuscule micro-optimizations, you should be prepared to have more unreadable code in the form of static fields

Comment: Spend your valuable time solving problems that are actually problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly your usecase, but maybe the `Lazy<T>` class will help.

```
    public static readonly Lazy<int> Something = new Lazy<int>(() => AccumulativeCount(() => 7));
    public static int AccumulativeCount(Expression<Func<int>> exp) {
        // usually do something useful with "exp". Instead put a
        // breakpoint and get the memory reference of exp via "&exp"
        return 1;
    }
    public static void DoSomething() {
        // the value was not available, so the AccumulativeCount(...) will be called
        var a = Something.Value;

        // the value is already created, no more call of AccumulativeCount(...) is needed
        var b = Something.Value;
        var c = Something.Value;
        var d = Something.Value;
    }
```